# Java: Is there an easy way to get an average when I have a collection of objects?

Tags: java, collections, average

So let's say I have a simple object:

```
public class Items {
    private static int 
        numItems,
        itemsInStock,
        itemsSold,
        //...
}
```

Elsewhere in the code I have an `ArrayList<Items>`

If there an easy way to get an average / median for numItems / ItemsInStock etc without needing to do a for/each on each field of the object?

Current code looks like :

```
for (Items item: allItems) {
    if (item.field != null) { 
        temp += item.field;
    }
}
fieldAvg = temp / allItems.size();
```

Comment: I don't really get the problem, is your way not easy enough ? If you want to do it fast for all fields, just copy and paste the code and replace each mention of the item.field.

Comment: You can stream and reduce the data.

Comment: @HopefullyHelpful

In the actual production code I have about 40 fields that I need to iterate through, which leads to some pretty gnarly repeated code.

Comment: If your fields are defined `static`, you are not going to get the results you thought you'd get. Remove that `static` keyword.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using a stream would arguably be more elegant:

```
double avg = allItems.stream().mapToInt(i -> i.itemsInStock).average().getAsDouble();
// Or any other field -------------------------^
```

Comment: Looks a lot better to me, I'll come back to this if I have implementation questions.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`IntSummaryStatistics`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/IntSummaryStatistics.html), with all its functionality `Average`, `Sum`, `Max`, .. :

```
int[] itemsInStock = allItems.stream().mapToInt(Items::getItemsInStock).toArray();

IntSummaryStatistics stat = IntStream.of(itemsInStock).summaryStatistics();

double average = stat.getAverage();
int max = stat.getMax();
int min = statistics.getMin();
long count = statistics.getCount();
long sum = statistics.getSum();
....
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible solution using a functional approach.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.ToIntFunction;

public class Items {
    // it doesn't make sense for the members to be static
    private /* static */ int
        numItems,
        itemsInStock,
        itemsSold,
        //...

    private static double getAverage(List<Items> allItems, ToIntFunction<Items> getter) {
        // assumption: average should be a double
        // assumption: zero should be returned if no items passed
        return allItems.stream().mapToInt(getter).average().orElse(0.0);
    }

    private static void doAverageCalcs(List<Items> allItems) {
        double numItemsAverage = getAverage(allItems, t -> t.numItems);
        double itemsInStockAverage = getAverage(allItems, t -> t.itemsInStock);
        double itemsSoldAverage = getAverage(allItems, t -> t.itemsSold);
        // ...

        // do stuff with the averages
    }

    // the rest of the class' implementation goes here...
}
```